# Outer Join column providing incorrect output

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, outer-join

SQL Newbie here. I have created the following query as shown below in GoogleBigQuery:

```
SELECT PART_DT as DATE, HOUR_NBR as XACT_HOUR_UTC, concat ('ID:', XACT_ID) as XACT_ID, c.CHANNEL as CHANNEL_ID, t.RQST_ID as VENDOR, t.HTL_CD as HOTEL_CODE, DERIVED_RATE_CD as RATE_CATEGORY,  ACTN_CD,
g.SELL_STRT_DT as SELL_START_DATE, g.RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT as STAY_START_DATE, 
DATE_DIFF (PART_DT,  g.SELL_STRT_DT, DAY) as DIFF_BOOK_DATE_LESS_SELL_DATE,
CK_IN_DT as CHECK_IN, CK_OUT_DT as CHECK_OUT, 
ADULT_GST_CNT as NUM_OF_ADULTS, CHILD_GST_CNT as NUM_OF_CHILD, CONCAT(STAT_CD, '-', STAT_DESC) as FULL_ERROR
FROM table.table.1 as t
FULL OUTER JOIN table.table.2 as g
ON (g.HTL_CD = t.HTL_CD and g.RATE_PLAN_CD = t.DERIVED_RATE_CD)
FULL OUTER JOIN table.table.3 as c
ON t.RQST_ID = c.RQST_ID
WHERE
PART_DT BETWEEN '2021-05-13' AND '2021-05-13' 
AND HOUR_NBR > 12
AND c.CHANNEL not like 'HGW'
--AND CK_IN_DT BETWEEN '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-26' 
--AND STAT_CD is not null 
--AND DERIVED_RATE_CD in ('IDH0G', 'IDH00', 'IDH10', 'IDH14', 'IDH15', 'IDHIB', 'IDHVC') 
--AND SUB_CHNL_3 like 'B2B'
AND TGT_SYS like '%ABC%' 
AND (OPER_NM like '%reate%eservati%' and OPER_NM not like '%Group%')
AND DATE_DIFF (PART_DT,  g.SELL_STRT_DT, DAY)  <=0   -- can also be <0, or between 3 and 11
AND g.HTL_CD like '%XXXXX%'
ORDER BY PART_DT, HOUR_NBR desc, t.RQST_ID, CK_IN_DT, t.HTL_CD
```

The results of this query shows the columns SELL_START_DATE is 2021-05-17 which is incorrect. The value should be 2021-03-19 and I cant figure out why its giving this wrong output.

When I do the following SQL Query not using the OUTER JOIN I get the correct column output for SELL_START_DATE 2021-03-19

```
select 
HTL_CD
, RATE_PLAN_CD
, concat('ID:',CORP_ACCT_ID) as CORP_ACCT_ID
, RATE_PLAN_NM
, SELL_STRT_DT
, SELL_END_DT
, RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT AS STAY_START_DATE
, RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_END_DT AS STAY_END_DATE
, RATE_PLAN_DESC
FROM table.table.2
WHERE 
--SELL_STRT_DT between '2021-05-01' and '2021-05-01'
SELL_STRT_DT <= '2021-05-01'  --sell date is today or in the past
AND RATE_PLAN_RSTRCT_STRT_DT > '2021-05-01'  --stay date is any date in the future
AND (RATE_PLAN_CD like 'ABCD2%')
AND HTL_CD like '%XXXXX%'
ORDER BY 1,2
--limit 2000
```

I feel like I am doing something wrong with my outer join as the database for table.table.2 has 2021-03-19 for the SELL_START_DATE column for that HTL_CD. I do not know why my outer join is giving me results for 2021-05-17. Accepting any advice.

Comment: Make it easy (and possible) to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Why do your think it should not return you that value? `DATE_DIFF (PART_DT,  g.SELL_STRT_DT, DAY)  <=0` - all days after `PART_DT`, no more restrictions on `g.SELL_STRT_DT`

Comment: Because when not using the Outer Join as shown in my second query. The database pulls the correct date of 2021-03-19. Also, when looking directly in the database the value shows as 2021-03-19 so I know 2021-05-17 is incorrect.

Comment: Removing the non important columns from the results. This is the output I receive for the Outer Join Query
DATE: 2021-05-13
HOTEL_CODE: XXXXX
RATE_CATEGORY: ABCD2
SELL_START_DATE: 2021-05-17

Comment: For my second query I receive the following:
HTL_CD: XXXXX
RATE_PLAN_CD: ABCD2
SELL_STRT_DT: 2021-03-19

I dont understand why my first query gives me 2021-05-17 but the second gives me 2021-03-19 for the SELL_STRT_DT when that column is pulled from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

Found my issue. Had nothing to do with the join tables. Was missing a COLUMN that was needed to filter the data. This was more internal.